# Query criteria with date values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to build a query with criteria in two different fields.

One will search through the company name, for which I use

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_Start_DS] & "*"
```

- If there is a corresponding value it is returned
- If the textbox value in my form equals null or "" then it brings me results based on values of my other textboxes.

I would like to do this with two date values as well.

If there is a date range, let's say 01/01/19 to 25/03/2019 then I would like to filter that field based on the range values provided in the textboxes.
In the event the textboxes should be empty I would like to ignore that criteria and bring results based on my textbox value for company name.

At the moment I am using

```
>=[Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_Start_DS] and <=[Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_End_DS]
```

- It returns the window of dates as requested if there is a value in both textboxes.
- It will not return any if the textboxes are left blank, which is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping `NZ` to the date fields with dates in case form controls are `NULL` where you set alternative equal to itself

```sql
    mydate >= NZ([Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_Start_DS], mydate)
AND mydate <= NZ([Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_End_DS], mydate)
```

Alternatively with `BETWEEN`:

```sql
mydate BETWEEN NZ([Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_Start_DS], mydate)
           AND NZ([Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_End_DS], mydate)
```

Do note: `NULL` (i.e., missing) in `mydate` column will be excluded with above condition. But there are workarounds for this need.

Answer (score 1):

You can include an `is null` alternative condition within your selection criteria, e.g.:

```sql
select * from YourTable where
(
    [Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_Start_DS] is null or 
    YourDate >=[Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_Start_DS]
) 
and 
(
    [Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_End_DS] is null or 
    YourDate <=[Forms]![Date_Search]![CMBLdays_End_DS]
)
```

That is to say, either the form value is blank (null) or your date field is within the date range defined by the form value.

Here, `YourDate` represents the date field to which your selection criteria is being applied.